# How to queue reloadGrid requests in jqGrid? Or how to disable the GET on load?

Tags: jqgrid

If I load or reload jqGrid on a GET that takes a while to process and then make a subsequent call to `$("#myJqGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");` while that first process is being called, then the second call never issues GET request.  Is there a way I can queue them up or cancel them?  Or any other ideas for handling this?  Don't want to confuse the user with a bunch of queued requests, where they think they are getting a response for a request they just made, but it's the result from the first one.

I don't think this would be so much of an issue for me if there was a clean way to disable jqGrid from making the GET on initial load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most easy way to prevent loading of jqGrid initially is to use `datatype: 'local'` at the initialization time. If you need really fill the grid with the data from the server should should first change the `datatype` to `'json'` or `'xml'` with respect of `setGridParam` and then trigger `reloadGrid`:

```js
$("#gridId").jqGrid('setGridParam', {datatype: 'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

jqGrid has **no** way to queue Ajax requests. If you really need to make many sequential Ajax requests you should make the next request inside of `loadComplete`. You can for example create an array of requests, test in `loadComplete` whether the array is empty. If it's not empty you can call `.trigger('reloadGrid')` inside of `setTimeout` callback and call [shift](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp) method of the array.

In the most cases you don't really need to implement the Ajax queue. See for example [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9244023/315935) as an example.

Comment: Changing the data type seems like a hack to me, though.  It'd be nice if there was a fetchDataOnFirstLoad option, but with a better name.

Comment: @Bradford: I'm not the owner of jqGrid code. You should post all your suggestion to [trirand](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/). You should don't forget, that there are currently vary much options already. The new option `fetchDataOnFirstLoad` which you suggest is equivalent to the usage of `datatype: 'local'` and setting `.jqGrid('setGridParam', {datatype: 'json'})` **without** reloading of the grid directly after creating of the grid. So the option which you need means more `dontLoadDataOnCreate`.