# Save the state Of Expanded Nodes in jqgrid tree Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, treegrid

I need to persist the Expanded State Of  **JQTree Gird**.If i reload the whole grid than It Should be retain the old expanded state .
Kindly tell me how to do it.

**Thanks in  Advance**

Comment: How?Can You Show me the sample code for That???

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599287/create-read-and-erase-cookies-with-jquery

Comment: Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SPATEN-TreeGrid2.htm) which I created for [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9202378/315935). It seems that it's exact answer on your question.

Comment: thanks  @Oleg .Your answer was Exact what i want.
But it takes time to reload.I have thousands of Node & Subnode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SPATEN-TreeGrid2.htm) which I created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9202378/315935). It seems that it's exact answer on your question.

If you need to load thousands of Node & Subnode you have to load not full TreeGrid at once. You can load *expended* nodes only. It will reduce the time of loading. The server have to fill `loaded` property of items which are expended. I recommend you to use `postData` to send to the server additional information about the nodes which need be expanded (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9244023/315935)). It will allows to load *only required* data from the server.

In my opinion the combination of saving of expanded nodes in `localStorage` (like in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9202378/315935)) and loading from the server all expanded nodes (like shortly described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9244023/315935)) will bring you to solution of your problem.