# jqGrid: Set in localStorage treegrid expanded after reloadGrid

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid, local-storage, treegrid

I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192276/send-expanded-treegrid-nodes-in-cookie/9202378#9202378) and I have downloaded the demo of Oleg but in my code it doesn't work.

I have a jqGrid with external PHP with Json.
I use a setinteval (1 second) to refresh the data in real time but when I explode a tree it closes immediately.

My javascript code into jQuery(document).ready(function():
`

```
    // odd even row
    var resetAltRows = function () {
            $(this).children("tbody:first").children('tr.jqgrow').removeClass('odd');
            $(this).children("tbody:first").children('tr.jqgrow:visible:odd').addClass('odd');
    };

    'use strict';
    var $grid = $('#list'),
        saveObjectInLocalStorage = function (storageItemName, object) {
            if (typeof window.localStorage !== 'undefined') {
                window.localStorage.setItem(storageItemName, JSON.stringify(object));
            }
        },
        removeObjectFromLocalStorage = function (storageItemName) {
            if (typeof window.localStorage !== 'undefined') {
                window.localStorage.removeItem(storageItemName);
            }
        },
        getObjectFromLocalStorage = function (storageItemName) {
            if (typeof window.localStorage !== 'undefined') {
                return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(storageItemName));
            }
        },
        myColumnStateName = function (grid) {
            return window.location.pathname + '#' + grid[0].id;
        },
        idsOfExpandedRows = [],
        updateIdsOfExpandedRows = function (id, isExpanded) {
            var index = $.inArray(id, idsOfExpandedRows);
            if (!isExpanded && index >= 0) {
                idsOfExpandedRows.splice(index, 1); // remove id from the list
            } else if (index < 0) {
                idsOfExpandedRows.push(id);
            }
            saveObjectInLocalStorage(myColumnStateName($grid), idsOfExpandedRows);
        },
        orgExpandRow = $.fn.jqGrid.expandRow,
        orgCollapseRow = $.fn.jqGrid.collapseRow;

     idsOfExpandedRows = getObjectFromLocalStorage(myColumnStateName($grid)) || [];

    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        url:'get_tree.php',
        datatype: "json",
        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
        jsonReader: {
                id: "id",
                cell: "",
                root: function (obj) { return obj.rows; },
                page: function () { return 1; },
                total: function () { return 1; },
                records: function (obj) { return obj.rows.length; },
                repeatitems: true
            },
            beforeProcessing: function (data) {
                var rows = data.rows, i, l = rows.length, row, index;
                for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    row = rows[i];
                    index = $.inArray(row[0], idsOfExpandedRows);
                    row[30] = index >= 0; // set expanded column
                    row[31] = true;       // set loaded column
                }
            },

        colNames:[...............],
        colModel :[
            {name:'id', index:'id', width:15, sortable: false, title: false,hidden: true},
            {name:'0', index:'0', classes:'piu', width:15, sortable: false, title: false},
            {..............}
            ],
        rowNum:100,
        viewrecords: true,
        autowidth: true,
        height: 'auto',
        loadonce:true,
        key: true,
           loadComplete: function() {
                var grid = this;
                resetAltRows.call(this);
                $(this).find('tr.jqgrow td div.treeclick').click(function(){
                    resetAltRows.call(grid);
                });
                $(this).find('tr.jqgrow td span.cell-wrapper').click(function(){
                    resetAltRows.call(grid);
                });
            },
        gridview: true,
        treeGrid: true,
        treeGridModel: "adjacency",
        ExpandColumn: '0',
        ExpandColClick: true
    });
    $.jgrid.extend({
        expandRow: function (rc) {
            alert('before expandNode: rowid="' + rc._id_ + '", name="' + rc.name + '"');
            updateIdsOfExpandedRows(rc._id_, true);
            return orgExpandRow.call(this, rc);
        },
        collapseRow: function (rc) {
            alert('before collapseNode: rowid="' + rc._id_ + '", name="' + rc.name + '"');
            updateIdsOfExpandedRows(rc._id_, false);
            return orgCollapseRow.call(this, rc);
        }
    });

    //REFRESH JSON
    setInterval(
        function() {
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid');
        }
    , 1000);
```

`

I have also change this

`row[30] = index >= 0;
row[31] = true;`

with the exactly position of "expanded" and "loaded" field of json.

Comment: Could you include response from `'get_tree.php'` (at least some rows). Additional it could be required that you include more full `colModel` definition. The usage of `name:'0'` could make problems. I recommend you to choose the value of `name` property which corresponds to name of identifier. Another problem: if the index 30 in `row[30]` is wrong then you could have all collapsed rows. You can validate in `beforeProcessing` that `this.p.colModel[30].name` is `"expanded"`.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.
One row of JSON:
`{"id":"13","0":"","1":"01","2":"","3":"12345","4":"asdasdasd","5":"59.67","6":"asd","7":"UL","8":"5","9":"04:13","10":"1","11":"40","12":"40","13":"38","14":"(5) 5","15":"2","16":"2","17":"2","18":"0","19":"0","20":"6","21":"24","22":"99","23":"1.874","24":"0_01|0","level":"0","parent":null,"isLeaf":false,"expanded":false,"loaded":true}`

Comment: More row of colModel:
`colModel :[
{name:'id', width:15, sortable: false, title: false,hidden: true},
{name:'0', index:'0', classes:'piu', width:15, sortable: false, title: false},
{name:'1', index:'1', width:20, sortable: true, title: false},
{name:'2', index:'2', width:15, sortable: false, title: false},
{name:'3', index:'3',  width:40, sortable: false, title: false},`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote in the comment that one row of JSON data looks like

```
{"id":"13","0":"","1":"01","2":"","3":"12345","4":"asdasdasd","5":"59.67",
"6":"‌​asd","7":"UL","8":"5","9":"04:13","10":"1","11":"40","12":"40","13":"38",
"14":"(5‌​) 5","15":"2","16":"2","17":"2","18":"0","19":"0","20":"6","21":"24",
"22":"99","23‌​":"1.874","24":"0_01|0",
"level":"0","parent":null,"isLeaf":false,"expanded":false‌​,"loaded":true}
```

It means that the format of data corresponds **not** `repeatitems: true` inside of `jsonReader`. Only because of the feature Autotedection of JSON format introduced in jqGrid 4.4.5 and fixed in jqGrid 4.5.0 (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3achange) and [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/autodetection-of-input-json-format/)) the grid will be filled. So I recommend you to use `jsonReader` with `repeatitems: false` or at least remove `repeatitems: false` which don't corresponds your data format.

To set `expanded` and `loaded` column you should use

```
row.expanded = index >= 0; // set expanded column
row.loaded = true;         // set loaded column
```

instead of

```
row[30] = index >= 0; // set expanded column
row[31] = true;       // set loaded column
```

Additionally you should use `row.id` instead of `row[0]` (see `index = $.inArray(row[0], idsOfExpandedRows)` in the code).

Probably you will need make more changes like above. I can't tests the code, so the above changes could be not full. In any way the above changes are really required.

Additionally I would be very careful with usage of integers as the column names. I would better change the names of columns from `"0"`, `"1"`, ...`"24"` to for example `"c0"`, `"c1"`, ...`"c24"` which more corresponds to names of identifiers and protect you additionally from id duplicates with rowids which you have also as integers (see `"id":"13"` and `"13":"38"`). It could save much your time in the future.

Comment: @FrancescoLangiulli: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you.

Comment: Keeping the LocalStorege, exists a way that at regular intervals automate the opening of a tree overwriting the value that has in memory? Example: I wish every 5 minutes jqGrid re-read values ​​of expanded and loaded originating in JSON ...

Comment: @FrancescoLangiulli: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. The function `updateIdsOfExpandedRows` will be called on every expanding or collapsing of rows of TreeGrid. What information in memory you need to overwrite? On the other side if you need reload the data from the server, then it could be in general **absolute new data**. I can't say directly which kind of validation of previously saved data in `localStorage` are really required in the case.

Comment: I want add a condition, when a value of hidden column have a certain value I want to expand one tree. Before `localStorage` implementation, when I generate the JSON via PHP, I wrote `expanded="true"` on the line that I would open automatically at reloadGrid. But now if I set to true the value is overwritten by `localStorage`.

Comment: @FrancescoLangiulli: Sorry, I am now full in preparing for my vocation together with my family. So I'm not able to help you now. Till the middle of August I will be not available. By the way, we'll fly to Italy, Sardinia. Best wishes!

Comment: I'm happy for you! No problem Oleg, you were already far too kind! Good holiday, Sardinia is beautiful place! See you soon

Comment: The solution is use `if(...){ updateIdsOfExpandedRows(id, true); }` in `gridComplete` if you want to overwrite an ID expanded status.