# How do I force a newline in a cell on a " " delimiter in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, html, jqgrid

So, basically what I'm trying to do is making it so when the server sends back results like:

```
"Car Boat House"
```

That jqgrid will populate them in a cell like:

```
Car
Boat
House
```

I'm using the css method of telling jqgrid to do multiline on this cell with this:

```
cellattr : function(rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
    return 'style="white-space: normal"';
}
```

Is there any way to do this?  Some kind of "preFill" method for jqGrid I didn't see that would let me substitute:

```
" "
```

for

```
"<br/>"
```

on the fly?

I had success forcing my server to jam in the break as the delimiter, but I wept as I wrote it and had to remove it immediately for fear of bursting into flames for sinful coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the value of the cell to a formatter function. See http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter

```
function myformatter ( cellvalue, options, rowObject )
{
  return cellvalue.replace(/\s/,'<br />');
}
```

Comment: This looks like it will work.  Thanks!  I should have seen that custom formatter in the documentation.  I will say the only issue I'm having with it is that "replace" appears to find the first instance, replace it, then exit.  I need like a replaceAll...

Comment: Ended up going with cellvalue.split(' ').join('<br />');

Comment: Add global flag "g" to pattern.
return cellvalue.replace(/\s/g,'<br />');

Comment: @Josh: I would better recommend to use `beforeProcessing` for the modification of the data (see the example in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9722466/315935) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9183407/315935)). The main advantage is: you can any formatter which you need. Additionally if you would use recommended option `autoencode: true` the data having symbols `<` or `>` in the text will be displayed correctly and will be not interpreted as HTML data.

Comment: @Brent: Look at the comment which I wrote to Josh.

Answer (score 1):

try using :

```
return 'style="text-wrap: normal"';
```

Update, or you could try this also:

```
return 'style="word-wrap:break-word"';
```

Comment: That doesn't actually force a newline or break between values.  It sets a text wrap based on the width of the column :/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying css to the grid after rendering. Try applying css to the table,

```
#tableID tr td {
    white-space: normal;
}
```